# Use external link in the add sub menu

Tags: wordpress

I want to show the data in the external plugins.php file. the below url path is correct but its not showing the file data. Whats the problem?

```
add_submenu_page( 'antify', 'Plugins', 'Plugins', 'manage_options', 'plugins', ANTIFY_PLUGIN_URL . '/admin/pages/plugins.php' );
```

**plugins.php**

```
<?php
echo 'Hello World';
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong method. Try this instead

```
add_plugins_page('MY TEST', 'My Plugin', 'read', 'my-unique-identifier', array($this,'test_plugin'));
```

then create the test_plugin function to include your php file.

```
function test_plugin() {
include(ANTIFY_PLUGIN_URL . '/admin/pages/plugins.php');
}
```

I tried this and it works on wordpress 4.1.